# Scroll to particular span in listview

Tags: android

I want to create view Quran Majeed ie multiple selectable parts of listview item.
[image: Quran Majeed app]

I have done this using Clickable span and I have managed to add Clickable functionality but I have a problem. I am implementing reciting on user click and listview should have to scroll during recitation.

[image: my app]

I have used

```
listview.scrollTo(0, onclickView.getY())
```

But gety() returns 0 every time

Comment: please provide more code so we can understant

Answer (score 0):

Use a recycler view instead and do the following:

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = ((LinearLayoutManager)mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager()); 

int lastVisiblePosition =layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
```

Next do the following:

```
mRecyclerView.smoothScrollTo(lastVisiblePosition);
```